# Use property value as method name

Tags: php

I need to use a value of a property in my class as a dynamic method name, but I am getting a:

```
 Catchable fatal error: Object of class dispatcher could not be converted to string in ...
```

What I want to do is:

```
 class test {
      var $objectname = "object_name";
      var $methodname = "method";

      public function test_method() {
           require_once("some_class_file");
           // Here is where I am falling out:
           $some_object = new $this->objectname();
           $some_object->$this->methodname();
      }
 }
```

So in other words I want to dynamically set the object name and potential methods from pre-existing properties in my class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was generated because of the following line :

```
 $some_object->$this->methodname();
```

Replace With  :

```
 $some_object->{$this->methodname}();
```